# Using configBuilders with system.webServer rewrite section

Tags: asp.net, environment-variables, web-config, url-rewrite-module, asp-net-config-builders

I use the IIS Url Rewrite module, which is configured under `system.webServer/rewrite`.

I'm trying to use a basic `Microsoft.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilders.EnvironmentConfigBuilder` configBuilder with `mode="Expand"` so I can inject an environment variable into my `<rewrite>` config section like so:

```
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        ...
        <section name="configBuilders" type="System.Configuration.ConfigurationBuildersSection, System.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" restartOnExternalChanges="false" requirePermission="false" />
        ...
    </configSections>
    ...
    <configBuilders>
        <builders>
            <add name="MyConfigBuilder" mode="Expand" type="Microsoft.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilders.EnvironmentConfigBuilder, Microsoft.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilders.Environment, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral" />
        </builders>
    </configBuilders>
    ...
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite configBuilders="MyConfigBuilder">
            <providers>
                <provider name="SomeProvider">
                    <settings>
                        <add key="someKey" value="${someEnvToken}" />
                    </settings>
                </provider>
            </providers>
            ...
        </rewrite>
    </sytem.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I get a `500 - Internal server error. There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.` with no stack trace or any further information. Visual studio intellisense states `The "configBuilders" attribute is not allowed` which I guess explains the 500 error.

If I try at any other level in the rewrite config, e.g. on the child element `<providers>` or `<provider>` or `<settings>` then I get a 500 error with  `Unrecognized attribute 'configBuilders'`

I've tried placing the `configBuilders` attribute on the `<system.webServer>` element itself, too, but there's still an error.

As far as I'm aware the attribute `configBuilders` needs to go on a `configSection` only. Which means `system.webServer` is out because it's a `configSectionGroup`. In theory, `rewrite` should be a `configSection` and therefore accept the attribute, no?

How do I get this to work with the url rewrite module? If it can't work, then I must ask: what's the point if all it can do is `appSettings` and `connectionStrings`? I'm aware you can create custom section handlers for your own custom sections. The problem is this isn't a custom section - it's a highly used module made by Microsoft and used by almost anyone running a website on IIS!

## --- EDIT ---

I've since discovered that the `<rewrite>` element is also a `configSectionGroup` but all of the child elements are `configSection` so it should work in theory. I found this link:

https://githubmemory.com/repo/aspnet/MicrosoftConfigurationBuilders/issues/149

Where a guy is creating his own `sectionHandler` for a well-known section `<customErrors>` which seems to work. I believe it instructs the configBuilders to process the section whereas otherwise it ignored it.

The class is declared like so:

```
public class CustomErrorsSectionHandler : Microsoft.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilders.SectionHandler<CustomErrorsSection>
```

Note that `CustomErrorsSection` is in `System.Web.Configuration` and is `public sealed`.

I've tried to replicate this by creating a `sectionHandler<Microsoft.Web.Management.Iis.Rewrite.ProvidersSection>` but it's `internal sealed` so it's not possible to implement.

Is this literally impossible??

Comment: I am having the same problem with `system.webServer.httpProtocol.customHeaders` section